# return returns the word array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code here:

```
function getproductList()
{
   global $woocommerce;
   $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
   $product_names=array();
    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
      $_product = $values['data']->post; 
      $product_names[]=$_product->post_title; 
    }     
 /*
    // if you want string then use 
    $allproductname=implode("",$product_names);
    return $allproductname;

 */
    return $product_names; 
}
```

Its a function that returns an array. Whenever i call the function it returns the word "Array" i used print_r and it gave me nothing.

I call this function like this:

```
// prepare the sales payload
$sales_payload = array(
    'organization_id' => $getOrg['data']['0']['id'],
    'contact_id' => $contact_id,
    'status' => 'Open',
    'subject' => " ".str_replace($strToRemove, "", $_POST['billing_myfield12'])." - ".getproductList(),
    'start_date' => date("Y-m-d"), // set start date on today
    'expected_closing_date' => date("Y-m-d",strtotime(date("Y-m-d")."+ 14 days")), // set expected closing date 2 weeks from now
    'chance_to_score' => '10%',
    'expected_revenue' => 0, //set the expected revenue
    'note' => $_POST['order_comments'],

    'progress' => array(
        'id'=>'salesprogress:200a53bf6d2bbbfe' //fill a valid salesprogress id to set proper sales progress 
    ),

    "custom_fields" => [["actief_in_duitsland"=>$value]],
);
```

Notice I called it here:

```
'subject' => " ".str_replace($strToRemove, "", $_POST['billing_myfield12'])." - ".getproductList(),
```

This used to work when i make a string of it

```
$allproductname=implode(" + ",$product_names);
return $allproductname;
```

Now i just want the array and its items. How do i do this?

Comment: `var_dump()`???

Comment: Let me try bro @PraveenKumar

Comment: Does not work @PraveenKumar

Comment: Yesterday i did something like Print_r($variable, true) and it worked but today its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling this line

```
str_replace($strToRemove, "", $_POST['billing_myfield12'])." - ".getproductList()
```

you are converting your array with product names to string.

Default array to string conversion is string "Array".

Use function implode instead, to join all product names into one string.

Or if you want an array of product names, use this

```
'product_names' => getproductList(),
```

Comment: I want the array in this case no string

Comment: Well dont join it into a string! How can you have an array when you join it to string? _POST['billing_myfield12'])." - ".getproductList()

Comment: Should i just call the function and remove  this str_replace($strToRemove, "", $_POST['billing_myfield12'])." - "